# Org-mode and python source code block -> ElDoc error wrong-type-argument

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, eldoc

When inside a python source code block in an .org file, I get the following error displayed on my mini buffer:

```
eldoc error: 
(wrong-type-argument symbolp #[128 \300\301"\206�\300\302"\207 
[apply python-eldoc-function #[128 \301\302\300!"\207 
[eldoc-documentation-function apply default-value] 4 
(fn &rest ARGS)] nil] 4 nil])
```

Has anyone ever come across this problem? 
I am running the latest org-mode under Emacs 25 on a OS X 10.11.1, and I use the anaconda python 2.7 distribution.

Comment: I didn't have this problem, but from how it sounds I'd imagine that what happens is something like so: `eldoc` is the Emacs package which provides minibuffer hints for the currently edited function (such as its arguments and a type). However, `eldoc` itself doesn't understand every language, so there are multiple extensions for different languages. There must be an extension for Python too. Probably, there's a problem with this extension. Likely, it needs the buffer being edited to have a physical file associated to it or some such.

Comment: @wvxvw thanks for the answer. I've installed elpy because I know it installs a bunch of Python related tools with it, and the problem disappeared. I didn't care to find out what I was missing, but it's likely to be some sort of eldoc extension, as you mentioned.